# Virtual Machines on a seprate vlan

Tags: vlan, private-vlan

My team has 100 developers. They each have a computer and on that computer, they have two nics facing our router. WiFi and their virtual machine (VMWare nic).

I would like to have a network inside of my network that is only comprimised of virtual machines.

```
Traffic from host -> main network -> internet
Traffic from VM   -> Virtual Network -> No internet connection
```

This way, my developers can have their virtual machines talking to each other (TCP/IP) yet their dev machines (virtual) don't have to be managed by IT.

I think VLans could be used in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, VLANs can be used this way.

What I'd do given that you have separate NICs for the VMs themselves, I'd set all switchports on the switch(es) as access ports to the new VLAN that connect to the VM NICs. This way, you don't have to reconfigure each VM/hypervisor to trunk mode on the specific VLAN.

That will allow all VMs to inter-communicate (depending on network security configuration of course) by default, pending a changing of IP addresses if the VM subnet is not currently separate from the main network's subnet.

You'll then have to trunk all switches together for the new VLAN, and depending on how you have the default gateway set up, you'll have to likely make changes to your router(s) as well, and transfer the default gw IP to the VLAN interface of the new VLAN.